# Unreal Engine - Scaleform - How do I capture a button click event?

Tags: udk, unreal

I'm new to Unreal Development.

In a nutshell, how do I create a button, install it in a basic game, and capture the button click event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Send of signals:

We can send messages from flash to UDK with the ActionScript command fscommand( "mycommand" )

For example, we want a button that permit us exit from the game

With ActionScript, we asign the function fscommand("exit") to the click button event

```
btn_exit.addEventListener( "click", this, "btn_exit_click" );

function btn_exit_click():Void
{
    fscommand("exit");
}
```

- Receiving message:

From kismet we can receive the pulsation of the button, for this:

New event -> GFx Ui -> fscommand
[image: .]

Inside the properties, we have two that are necessary, Movie and FSCommand

On Movie we'll put the flash movie that we are using ( button with green arrow ) and in FSCommand we write the command that we are waiting for, in that case Exit

[image: .]

- Send of signals:

We can connect the exit to that we want to happen when the signal was sended from Flash.

With this example, we are created a "Console Command"

New Action -> Misc -> Console Command

[image: .]

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is outdated. FScommands are deprecated and slow.

Try using scaleform CLIK and:

```
event bool WidgetInitialized(name WidgetName, name WidgetPath, GFxObject Widget)
{

    // Determine which widget is being initialized and handle it accordingly
    switch(Widgetname)
    {
        case 'btnStart':
            // Save reference to the label that displays the message to the player
            btnStart = GFxCLIKWidget(Widget);
            btnStart.AddEventListener('CLIK_click', startGame);
            break;

        default:
            // Pass on if not a widget we are looking for
            return Super.WidgetInitialized(Widgetname, WidgetPath, Widget);
    }

    return false;
}

function startGame(EventData data)
{
    // Only on left mouse button
    if(data.mouseIndex == 0)
    {
        ConsoleCommand("open DM-DECK");
    }
}
```